# Multiple displays: screen wrapped ubuntu 14.04.01

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

Since december 2014, one of my two screens is wrapped around itself (see [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47319885/printscreen_splitscreen.jpg)).
Furthermore, the mouse is lagging on the wrapped screen. I tried rebooting, switching on/off the screen, plugging it in and out but the issue remains. However, if I select the same resolution for both screens, it works fine (but since one screen has a low resolution and has a 5:4 aspect ratio, this is not desirable). Interestingly, the desktops appear correct on printscreen images. Furthermore, it is always the display on the right side (set to be on the right side in the system tools) that is wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent update solved the problem